# Ключевое слово __makeref C#

Tags: c#

Нашел вот такой вот код:

```
object o = new object();
TypedReference tr = __makeref(o);
```

Запустил и хотел посмотреть что внутри `tr` через точку остановки, но не получается. Зачем этот код вообще нужен и когда это может пригодиться? К тому же, не могу даже получить тип с помощью `tr.GetType()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945057/12888024

Comment: @aepot спасибо!

Comment: И [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764573/2881286)